# How to efficiently work with a task stream?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

**Disclaimer: I let the question open, but my slow branching issue was due to the server being overloaded. So this is not the usual Perforce behavior. I now take about 30 seconds to branch 10K files.**

I am a new Perforce 2014 user. I have created a stream depot, and put the legacy application (about 10,000 cpp files) in a development branch. That was relatively quick for an initial import, about 1 hour to upload everything.

Now I want to create a 'lightweight' task stream to work on a new feature.
I use the default menu > new stream > type task ... I select "Branch file from parent on stream creation"

To my surprise, it takes ages (about 1 hour) to create a new task because it is branching individually every file. I would expect the process to be almost instant coming from other SCM tools. (git, svn,...)

Now my question is :

- is this the expected behavior ?
- Alternatively, is there a way to create more quickly a Task, and only branch the file I intend to modify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new task stream of 10k files SHOULD be a very quick operation (on the order of a second or two?) since no actual file content is being transferred, assuming you're starting with a synced workspace.  If you're creating a brand new workspace for the new stream, then part of creating the new workspace is going to be syncing the files; I'd expect that to take about as long as the submit did since it's the same amount of data being transferred.

Make sure when creating a new stream that you're not creating a new workspace.  In the visual client there's an option to "create a workspace"; make sure to uncheck that box or it'll make a new workspace and then sync it, which is the part that'll take an hour.

From the command line, starting from a workspace of //stream/parent, here's what you'd do to make a new task stream:

```
p4 stream -t task -P //stream/parent //stream/mynewtask01
p4 populate -r -S //stream/mynewtask01
p4 client -s -S //stream/mynewtask01
p4 sync
```

The "stream" and "client" commands don't actually operate on any files, so they'll be really quick no matter what.  The "populate" will branch all 10k files, but it does it on the back end without actually moving any content around, so it'll also be really quick (if you got up into the millions or billions it might take an appreciable amount of time depending on the server hardware, but 10k is nothing).  The "sync" will be very quick if you were already synced to //stream/parent, because all the files are already there; again, it's just moving pointers around on the server side rather than transferring the file content.

Comment: This is definitely an issue with the populate command, not the sync. Typically the sync is 1 or 2 min.  I have found a workaround for the time being, I'll keep investigating further. Thanks for letting me now this is not the usual behavior.

Comment: The first thing I'd investigate would be pre-submit triggers, if any -- the populate should be really fast, but it does fire triggers, and if you have, say, a code checker that fires as a trigger, then it's probably pulling down all the files to run its tests before it lets the populate proceed.  Other things to check for might be unusual filetype options like +S (which forces physical copying) or +k (which forces digest recomputation).

Comment: I have now understood the sync was done locally with the edge server, and the branch/populate on the master server. It is possible the master server was overloaded, which would explain why the branching was slow while other syncing were rather quick.

Comment: I have been working a bit longer with the server, it was definitely a transitory server side issue. It now takes about 1 minute to branch 10K files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Samwise your approach works and is really fast. Now compare to `p4 switch`. What's the recommend command to use? `p4 switch` is really slow though.

Comment: `p4 switch` is now the recommended command; I don't think it existed yet at the time I posted this answer.  It's basically just a shortcut for the above operations plus a few other things.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, which speed up things a bit, and is actually closer to what I intend to do :

Task streams are created by default with the following "stream view"

```
share ...
```

I have replaced it by

```
import ...
share /directory/I/actually/want/to/modify/...
```

So I skip the branching of most of the file, and it is working fine.